# how to merge two header file in C#?

Tags: c#

I have two files as follows:
first file1.txt -

```
 4
 suzan w kieth
 Terry s Greenberg
 Ron   q xxx
 Tu    L ip
```

second file file2.txt -

```
2
Lily s great
Rowina q Joseph
```

Both files first record is the number of records in that file and both files have exactly same format.

I want to have a third file which will have following records -

```
6
suzan w kieth
Terry s Greenberg
Ron   q xxx
Tu    L ip
Lily s great
Rowina q Joseph
```

Any suggestions how can I merge these files?
or the fastest way to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Convert string to int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx)

[TextReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.textreader.readline)

[TextReader.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.writeline.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace csharp_station.howto
{
    class TextFileReader
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TextReader tr1 = new StreamReader("file1.txt");
            TextReader tr2 = new StreamReader("file2.txt");
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("result.txt");

            int count1 = Convert.ToInt32(tr1.ReadLine());
            int count2 = Convert.ToInt32(tr2.ReadLine());
            tw.WriteLine(count1 + count2);

            for(int i = 0; i < count1; i++)
            {
                tw.WriteLine(tr1.ReadLine());
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
            {
                tw.WriteLine(tr2.ReadLine());
            }

            tr1.Close();
            tr2.Close();
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
var file1Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1Path);
var file2Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file2Path);
int totalCount = int.Parse(file1Lines.First()) + int.Parse(file2Lines.First());
var file3FirstLine = new[] { totalCount.ToString() };
var file3Lines = file3FirstLine.Concat(file1Lines.Skip(1))
                               .Concat(file2Lines.Skip(1));
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file3Path, file3Lines);
```